# Suddenly, I am getting an error: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document

Tags: android, android-studio-4.0

I have suddenly got this error after I have updated the Android Studio to 4.0.1

Comment: logs -> screenshots something atleast

Comment: I have updated the plugin that's why this error occurred, now fixed this to revert back the plugin update.
I am late but just wanted to know if someone gets help.